# Why we don't directly multiply given t in sinusoidal signal formula?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Formula is that:

$$V=V_{m}\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$

And question says:

**Question) $V=300\cos(120\pi t + 30^{\circ} )$ What is the magnitude of V at t=2.778mss?**

I didn't understand that in the solution we didn't directly use value of the **t**. Because the solution is:

$$\omega t = \frac{2\times\pi\times2.778\times 10^{-3} }{16.667\times10^{-3}}$$

$$v(2.778ms)= 300\cos(60^{\circ}+30^{\circ})= 0\,V $$

Comment: You probably misread the formula, since it has no $t$ in it. Perhaps you want $120\pi t + 30$.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Sorry, I forgot added the t. Now, I added. But my question is same :(. Why we didn't directly said $120\pi \times2.778\times 10^{-3}$

Comment: There is no difference between what you are saying and what the solution is saying. The given solution just wrote it a little differently (to be able to see $\omega t=2\pi/6$ easily). It's like trying to find 19+19: someone will do it as 10+10+9+9, someone will do it as 2*(10-1), etc. Nothing to really question there

Comment: @Raad Shaikh But after multiplication of t, it's divided by a another number.

Comment: @XcellentEEE $16.667\times 10^{-3}=1/60$, so $\omega=120\pi=2\pi\times 60=2\pi/(16.667\times10^{-3})$

Comment: In fact given the input to three decimal places you can't know the answer exactly. The $0$ value is only approximate. And the $30^\circ$ has only one significant figure. Estimating the actual error is tricky, but I would want so see something like $0.000$..

Comment: Thanks (: @Raad Shaikh. I don't have enough reputation score, sorry for I couldn't give (+).

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Thanks (:. I don't have enough reputation score, sorry for I couldn't give (+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $t = 2.778 ms$,

$V(t) = 300 \cos( 120 \times \pi \times 2.778 \times 10^{-3} + 30^\circ)$

Since $30^\circ = \pi/6$, you can write:

$V(t) = 300 \cos( 120 \times \pi \times 2.778 \times 10^{-3} + \pi/6)$

$V(t) \approx 300 \cos(\pi/3 + \pi/6) = 300 \cos(\pi/2) = 0$

There is some numerical approximation here. $120 \times 2.778  \times 10^{-3}$ is approximately 1/3, but not exactly. You can of course plug in the exact value of $t$ to get the exact answer $-0.02513$.

It is not a very well framed question or solution.